# Stack result of Query in a single row

Tags: google-sheets

My question is - How to transpose N x M query result to single row where order is as follows

Input table

```
Col1Row1 Col2Row1 Col3Row1
Col1Row2 Col2Row2 Col3Row2
```

To

```
Col1Row1 Col2Row2 Col3Row1 Col1Row2 Col2Row2 Col3Row2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FLATTEN`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(A1:C2))
```

[image]